# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `cats`)

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I am building a basic CRUD app using Laravel 7 Homestead in a Vagrant VM. The root address `http://crud-app.local.test` works, but when I add a defined route (`http://crud-app.local.test/cats`) I get this error page:

[Error message in browser when navigating to '/cats' route.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp83c.png)

So far I have:

- Verified my MySQL password matches in the `.env` file and in practice
- Changed the MYSQL password so that it's no longer empty (and made sure it matches what's in the `.env` file)
- Ran `php artisan config:cache`
- Ran `php artisan config:clear` followed by `php artisan cache:clear`
- Changed `127.0.0.1` to `localhost`
- Made sure the database defined in the `.env` file exists (`crud`)
- Ran `php artisan migrate` (no errors, and the `cats` table exists in the `crud` database)
- Restarted and re-provisioned the machine (`vagrant reload --provision`)

I'm at a loss now.

Comment: Can you connect to the database (from the command line, or tool of your choice) explicitly using user 'root', as opposed to not specifying a user at all?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you give "root" permissions to read from the database that you've created. As it's root@localhost rather than root@127.0.0.1 sometimes mysql differentiates. Just check the permissions that root@localhost has for the database and if you update them, flush the privileges.

Comment: I used `mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';` and then tried `mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON crud.* TO 'root'@'localhost';`, flushed privileges, and then cleared all caches and re-provisioned the virtual machine. Still same error page.